# How can automatically print a page bigger than an A4 on multiple A4 pages?

Tags: printing, image-processing

I have an image bigger than A4 (210x297 mm), let's say 400x400 mm. Is there a way to automaically print it on multiple pages keeping the original size, so that I can just put them side by side to get my orignal image?

I dont' mind small margins on each page (I can cut them away later) but I need to keep the original size.

Comment: That should be a function of the printer driver - which comes in thousands of flavors, as every printer manufacturer makes his own.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate which OS you are using, what printer you have and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an automatic solution, but I found PosteRazor, which allows to "cut" the image in multiple smaller ones with the desired settings (output size, margin size, border overlaying and some others)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: GIMP**

I am sharing `GIMP` solution from [Slicing Images Using GIMP - The Manual and Semi-Automatical Way](https://www.gamedev.net/tutorials/visual-arts/slicing-images-using-gimp-the-manual-and-semi-automatical-way-r5257/) post

download plungins:

1. https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/reviews
2. https://github.com/khalim19/gimp-plugin-export-layers/releases

Install both plugins into C:\Users"Your-Username"\AppData\Roaming\GIMP\2.10\plug-ins

Now open GIMP and go to layers > tiles > split tiles > choose number of rows and columns as you require.  and click OK.

Now go to Files > export layers and you can export tiles from your image like this to print later.

**Method 2: ImageMagick**

I share this solution from [Can GIMP split an image into multiple images?](https://superuser.com/questions/20081/can-gimp-split-an-image-into-multiple-images)  post.  for that you have to install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). Open terminal in folder where you have kept your image and type in terminal.

```
  convert -extract 1024x1024+0+0 original.png target.png
```

Where:

- *1024x1024* is the width and height of the required crop
- *+0+0* are x and y offsets into the original image

You can stick dozens of these commands into a .cmd file and run them effortlessly.

Look at the ImageMagick documentation to see there are thousands of options to these commands. A very powerful tool and open source too!

Edit: To split image into many images with this command you can run like this:

```
convert -extract 102x102+0+0 aa.jpg target.png -extract 102x102+102+0 aa.jpg target1.png -extract 102x102+204+0 aa.jpg target2.png -extract 102x102+0+102 aa.jpg target3.png -extract 102x102+0+204 aa.jpg target4.png
```

Here you have to manually calculate size of output image and offsets and edit the command script accordingly. This way you can add as many extract command as you need.

Comment: GIMP looks a bit overpowered for my needs in this case (and I prefer to keep my installation clean), so I tried ImageMagick, but the provided commands just gives me the top left corner of the source image. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: my bad I have edited answer for ImageMagick. please see.